# Which method to use for flicker free images in vb.net in a closed enviroment?

Tags: vb.net, sdl, gdi+

I'm having trouble locating a method for drawing multiple (10-20) images (alpha'd PNG's) onto a form in vb.net without huge flicker.
The main problem is i'm in an closed environment - I can't install any SDKs (so no DirectX) or redist's (so no XNA)
My first thought was GDI+ but I cant find a way that doesn't flicker. A friend recommended SDL using a SDL to C# wrapper, though I'm having trouble as all the c++ tutorials and for speed I'd like to keep the inbuilt winforms functionality if I'm honest.
Is anyone able to suggest a better solution?

Edit: Here's my basic code. It flickers whenever its repainted (i.e. the mouse moves onto or off the form background such as over another control on the form) or when I was using the commented-out timer control (even with a 1s refresh) instead of the onpaint event

```
Public Class Form1

Dim sprite As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\test\1.png")
Dim background As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\test\2.png")
Dim x As Integer = 20
Dim gfx As Graphics

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    gfx.DrawImage(background, 0, 0, background.Width, background.Height)
    gfx.DrawImage(sprite, x + 50, x + 50, sprite.Width, sprite.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    x = x + 10
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    gfx = Me.CreateGraphics
End Sub

'Private Sub smoothPainter_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles smoothPainter.Tick
'    gfx.DrawImage(background, 0, 0, background.Width, background.Height)
'    gfx.DrawImage(sprite, x + 50, x + 50, sprite.Width, sprite.Height)
'End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: GDI+ should be able to handle that easily.  Can you edit your question to include what you've done so far that flickered so badly?

Comment: hard to tell anything without some code showing how they are drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a static graphics object. Use the graphics object provided by the PaintEventArgs variable.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(background, 0, 0, background.Width, background.Height)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(sprite, x + 50, x + 50, sprite.Width, sprite.Height)
End Sub
```

Also enable double buffering on the form

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub
```

You would also probably need to refresh the form after the button click

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    x = x + 10
    Me.Invalidate() 'Or Me.Refresh if you want to force an instant redraw
End Sub
```

It's also often faster/better to draw on an image first and then draw the image onto the form (basically that's what a Double Buffer does).

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Using Bmp as New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height) 
      Using g as Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
         g.DrawImage(background, 0, 0, background.Width, background.Height)
         g.DrawImage(sprite, x + 50, x + 50, sprite.Width, sprite.Height)
      End Using
      e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(b, 0, 0)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks. Works a lot better now. I thought double buffering on forms was the default though?